# Angular form builder validation at least one property in object is true

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to make the form invalid if one of these checkboxes are not true. 
Here's how I have written my HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-12 labelparent" formGroupName="Source">
    <label class="col-md-3">DAM Source </label>
    <span class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name="referenceType"
                           formControlName="DAMSource"
                           id="DAMSourcecheckbox" />
                    <label for="DAMSourcecheckbox">DAM</label>

                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name="referenceType"
                           formControlName="ContentStudioSource"
                           id="ContentStudioSourceheckbox" />
                    <label for="ContentStudioSourceheckbox">Contentstudio</label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name="referenceType"
                           formControlName="LocalSource"
                           id="LocalSourcecheckbox" />
                    <label for="LocalSourcecheckbox">Custom</label>
              </span>
</div>
```

And my formGroup

```
 'Source': this.fb.group({
              DAMSource: false,
              ContentStudioSource: false,
              LocalSource: false
            })
```

How do I add a validator on this, where the form is invalid if no checkbox is clicked, or in the Source object none of they key is true?

Comment: Try using required attribute with input tags and kindly give different names to all inputs otherwise it'll cause a big problem of checking all when you check any one of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic gist of how you can do it.

I prepared a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfpxgm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideExplorer=1) but I'm not sure its working

```
  keys = ['ck1','ck2','ck3','ck4','ck5','ck6'];

  fg: FormGroup;

  constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fg = this.buildForm();

  }

  buildForm(): FormGroup {
    let group = {};

    this.keys.forEach(k => group[k] = new FormControl(false));

    return this.fb.group(group, { validator: this.truthyValidator() });
  }

  truthyValidator() {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      this.keys.forEach(k => { 
        if (group.controls[k].value === false) 
          group.controls[k].setErrors({ falsey: 'Cannot be false' });
        else
          group.controls[k].setErrors(null);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator for your nested group, which checks that at least one checkbox is checked.

```ts
'Source': this.fb.group({
   DAMSource: false,
   ContentStudioSource: false,
   LocalSource: false
}, { validator: this.checkChk })
```

and the custom validator:

```ts
checkChk(group: FormGroup) {
   return Object.keys(group.controls).some(x => group.controls[x].value === true) ? 
         null : { notValid: true }
}
```

... where we return `null` if at least one checkbox is check, which means the form is valid, or then `notValid` if form is not valid. You can display error in template with referring to this error error name.

Here's a demo (where `Source` in this case is the parent formgroup): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pv2bsa?file=src/app/app.component.ts